# Excel with visual basic SQL query deletes formuals when records are changed

Tags: sql, vb.net, excel

So I'm fairly new to visual basic, not so much SQL, but I've found a piece of code online that I've edited and I have it working like I need to bring data into the Excel sheet. The problem is, when I change parameters to look for a different record set, if I have forumlas looking at the data in the table (example: sheet2 formula looks at sheet1 A1) the formula itself gets deleted and changed to "#REF!". I've tried dollar signs and that didn't work. I've even tried commenting out the line that clears the table after the parameter is changed too. Is there a query table option that I can set? Or is there a different way to display the results rather than a query table?

Visual Basic snippet:

```
Sub ParameterQueryExample()
'---creates a ListObject-QueryTable on Sheet1 that uses the value in
'        Cell A1 as the ProductID Parameter for an SQL Query
'        Once created, the query will refresh upon changes to A1.

Dim sSQL As String
Dim qt As QueryTable
Dim rDest As Range


'--build connection string-must use ODBC to allow parameters
Const sConnect = "ODBC;" & _
    "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};" & _
    "Server=Braden-PC;" & _
    "Database=CI_APEXALPHA;"

'--build SQL statement
        sSQL = "SELECT *" & _
        " FROM apexalpha.CI_AAD_SAMPLE" & _
        " WHERE SAMPLE_DESCRIPTION = ?;"

    '--create ListObject and get QueryTable
Set rDest = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")
'--rDest.CurrentRegion.Clear  'optional- delete existing table


Set qt = rDest.Parent.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSrcExternal, _
    Source:=Array(sConnect), Destination:=rDest).QueryTable


'--add Parameter to QueryTable-use Cell Z1 as parameter
With qt.Parameters.Add("SAMPLE_DESCRIPTION", xlParamTypeVarChar)
    .SetParam xlRange, Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
    .RefreshOnChange = True
End With


'--populate QueryTable
With qt
    .CommandText = sSQL
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True  'add any other table properties here
    .BackgroundQuery = False
'--    .Refresh

End With


Set qt = Nothing
Set rDest = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your new query table is destroying the cell references in your formulas.  If you have a formula pointing to a cell and you delete the cell (not just the contents but the entire cell) the reference is broken and you get the error.  Your code is creating a new query table each time it runs so it's deleting the old.  Instead you can set the query as the qt's source, change the parameter and use qt.refresh.

Without knowing your objective and formulas, it's hard to tell if there is a better way.

Comment: Is there any other information I can provide that would help you understand better?